# "Access is denied" when changing a file's attributes

Tags: powershell

I have a PS script that is trying to change the attributes (archive flag) of a file but I am receiving an access to path is denied error.

The user I am logged on as is a member of the local Administrators group, and can change the attributes without a problem by right-clicking the file.

The script is allowed to write these files to this folder in the first place, just not change their attribute.

Does anyone know what other security setting I may need to change?

Thank you in advance.

-Ben

Edit - Code:

```
$file=get-item E:\Transfer\In\Data\EAS\BALSHEET.txt
if(Test-Path $file){
    $file.attributes.GetType().Name
    $a = $file.attributes
    if($a -eq "Archive"){
        Copy-Item $file 'E:\FDM_Apps\Main\Inbox\_Data From Transfer'
        Copy-Item $file 'E:\Transfer\Archive\In Archive\Data\EAS'
        $ArchiveFile = get-item 'E:\Transfer\Archive\In Archive\Data\EAS\BALSHEET.txt'
        $ArchiveName = 'BALSHEET'+$date+'.txt'
        Rename-Item $ArchiveFile $ArchiveName
        $file.Attributes="Normal"   #Error occurs on this line
    }
}
```

Comment: Care to share some code? It doesn't sound like a security setting from your description.

Comment: Sorry, code added.  $file.Attributes="Normal" is causing my error.

Comment: Are your console or ise run as administrator?

Comment: Hmm, perhaps it is permissions after all, because the code looks fine. I ran it here and it worked for me. Is the file in use perhaps?

Comment: @BenFinkel It's probably NTFS (or whatever file security) permissions that's missing from the account running the script. I get 'Access is denied', if I remove my rights from a file, but otherwise that line is fine. What error are you getting?

Comment: It's odd because earlier in the script the file in question is being copied to it's target location, so the script clearly has write permission there.